# How to enable Compiz for Gnome3?

Tags: 11.04, compiz, gnome

After installing Gnome 3 the Compiz plugins are not working on the gnome-shell.

Is there a way to enable the Compiz on Gnome3 shell??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GNOME Shell uses its own compoziting window manager called Mutter. According to Owen Taylor's mail it is not possible to use an alternative window manager.

> To try and make GNOME Shell integrate
>   with multiple window managers would
>   either greatly constrain the user
>   interface vision or greatly increase
>   the amount of work involved. The power
>   of the GNOME shell approach is that we
>   are working within the desktop scene
>   graph of the window
>   manager/compositor.
>
> Using Compiz to create a GNOME desktop
>   using GNOME applications, the GNOME
>   control-center, and so forth will of
>   course remain possible. We have no
>   current plans to create hard
>   dependencies on GNOME Shell within the
>   GNOME desktop (just as there are no
>   hard dependencies on gnome-panel now.)

http://www.mail-archive.com/desktop-devel-list@gnome.org/msg15587.html

Answer (score 2):

According to this post on the [Fedora Forums](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showpost.php?p=1477605&postcount=2), as well as a [message on the mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/desktop-devel-list@gnome.org/msg15587.html), the answer is that Compiz and gnome-shell cannot work together.

> To try and make GNOME Shell integrate
>   with multiple window managers
>
> would either greatly constrain the
>   user interface vision or greatly
>
> increase the amount of work involved.
>   The power of the GNOME shell
>
> approach is that we are working within
>   the desktop scene graph of the
>
> window manager/compositor.
>
> Using Compiz to create a GNOME desktop
>   using GNOME applications, the
>
> GNOME control-center, and so forth
>   will of course remain possible. We
>
> have no current plans to create hard
>   dependencies on GNOME Shell within
>
> the GNOME desktop (just as there are
>   no hard dependencies on gnome-panel
>
> now.)

Answer (score 0):

**I can't use Compiz with GNOME Shell!**

Because the GNOME Shell project wanted "tighter integration" between the panel and window manager than cooperating with the Compiz project would allow, this could actually be true. This [mailing list post](http://www.mail-archive.com/desktop-devel-list@gnome.org/msg15602.html) has more information.

<sup>1</sup> Source [Gnome Live](http://live.gnome.org/GNOME3Myths)