# Use compiz on startup, compiz --replace bad?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, compiz, metacity

I want to run compiz on startup instead of the default window manager in the Gnome Classic Gnome Shell Fallback. My problem is that I can't find the "correct" way to do this. I have tried a bunch of stuff, e.g.

http://www.jejik.com/articles/2008/10/how_to_properly_start_compiz_in_gnome/

which doesn't work. The only way that have worked for me is using compiz --replace at startup but this slows down the startup, right? I mean, if I use the default window manager and i also have the compiz --replace at startup, wont it cause a slower startup when both the default window manager and compiz are launched (even though one is terminated)?

I also have the windowmanager set to compiz in the

```
"desktop->gnome->session->required_components"
```

in gconf-editor and it still doesn't work.

Any idea how I can disable the default window manager and use Compiz instead?

BTW: Im using ubuntu 11.10

Comment: Compiz *uses* Metacity under the Ubuntu session, Mutter *uses* Metacity under the Gnome Session (Gnome Shell). if you disable Metacity you will not have Window borders.

Comment: @UriHerrera If I enter compiz in a terminal, without the replace flag I get this message: (compiz:3845): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to parse /home/euhiemf/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini: Key file does not start with a group
compiz (core) - Error: Screen 0 on display ":0" already has a window manager; try using the --replace option to replace the current window manager. so which window manager is ubuntu using by default?

Comment: In the Ubuntu Session, Compiz **is** already running, since Unity is a Compiz plug in. You don't have to *add* anything.

Comment: The link you put in your question is for 2008, When Gnome 2 users used Compiz to have compositing and you'd add it at start up to have that, in 11.10 it's not necessary, unless you're running XFCE or LXDE which doesnt use compositing by default or if you want to replace Kwin in KDE.

Comment: @UriHerrera ok, when I log in I use the GNOME classic thing (don't know what you call them, sessions?) so Unity is disabled, or its not a startup app

Comment: Gnome Classic (Gnome Shell Fallback) doesn't use Compiz it Uses Mutter, it's own compositing engine.

Comment: @UriHerrera Ok, thanks, but should I change the Gnome Shell Fallback then or is there a way to change this Gnome Shell Fallback so that it uses compiz?

Comment: No. http://askubuntu.com/questions/47474/how-to-enable-compiz-for-gnome3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start off with telling that compiz *is* the default for Gnome-Classic in Ubuntu 12.04. So you might just want to upgrade. The Gnome-Classic session received lots of love in Ubuntu 12.04 and really works like the good old Ubuntu desktop.

On session configuration: The sessions are configured in `/usr/share/xsessions` where *gnome.desktop* is the default session. The .desktop session files usually run something like `gnome-session --session=ubuntu` or `gnome-session --session=gnome-classic`.

These refer to files located in `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions` where you can tell the specific session which window-manager to use.